# Can't get django_markdown working on the admin site

Tags: python, django, markdown, pythonanywhere

I have a Django server on [Pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/shiftry123/consoles/) and I'm dealing with a problem that is too difficult for me. On my local machine I had created a blog app which uses django_markdown. Markdown editors are showing correctly on the admin site.

However, when I try to do same thing on [Pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/shiftry123/consoles/) server I can't do anything to make the markdown editors show on the admin site.

Here are my files:

**url.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^markdown/', include('django_markdown.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...      
    'django_markdown',
    ...
)
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)

MARKDOWN_EDITOR_SKIN = 'simple'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django_markdown.models import MarkdownField

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = MarkdownField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Article"
        verbose_name_plural = "Articles"
        ordering = ["-created"]
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models
from django_markdown.admin import MarkdownModelAdmin

class ArticleAdmin(MarkdownModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("title", "created")

admin.site.register(models.Article, ArticleAdmin)
```

Statics are collected.

Comment: quick check- you do have django_markdown "pip installed" right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 2.x, you need to add the following line to your `ArticleAdmin` class:

```
# Workaround for Python 2.x
formfield_overrides = {TextField: {'widget': AdminMarkdownWidget}}
```

Be sure to add the following import at the beginning as well:

```
from django_markdown.widgets import AdminMarkdownWidget
```

Comment: Also don't forget to import this. **from django.db.models import TextField**